# Can't handle single sentences with multiple words. But everything seems ok

Tags: c, cs50

I'm trying to do the readability quest (from *cs50*) and I thought my program was working fine, but when I tried to evaluate the correctness of my code using check50 it showed me this:

> ":( handles single sentence with multiple words
>       expected "Grade 7\n", not "text\nGrade 8...""

and this was the only result wrong, the rest was green and correct.

What am I doing wrong?

Here's my code

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <math.h>

int main (void)
{
    string text = get_string ("Text: ");
    printf ("text\n");
    int letters=0,words=1,sentences=0;

    for (int i = 0; i < strlen(text); i++)   
    {    
        if ((text[i] >= 'a' && text[i] <= 'z' ) || (text[i] >= 'A' && text[i] <= 'Z'))
        {
            letters++;     
        }  
        else if (text[i]== ' ')
        {
            words++;        
        }       
        else if ((text[i])== '.' || (text[i]) == '!' || (text[i]) == '?')
        {
            sentences++;    
        }    
    }   

    float L = letters * 100 / words;
    float S = sentences * 100 / words;
    float index = 0.0588 * L - 0.296 * S - 15.8;
    if (index >= 16) 
    {
        printf ("Grade 16+\n");       
    }
    else if (index < 1) 
    {
        printf ("Before Grade 1\n"); 
    }
    else
    {       
        printf ("Grade %i\n",(int) round(index));
    }
}
```

- word - any sequence of characters separated by a space to be a word.
- sentence - any sequence of characters that ends with ("?".".","!")

Comment: Thanks for the info. How about corner cases.  Is `" "`, `""` 0 words? Is `"abc"`, `"abc "`, `" abc"`, `" abc "`, `"123"`, `" .  "` all 1 word?  Is a double, triple, etc. space the same impact on word count as a single space?  Are tabs, new-line the same impact as space character?  `"Hello World"` is zero sentences as it lacks ("?".".","!")?

Comment: The CS50 exercise assumes that the our C programm does not need to handle all this exceptions.

Answer (score 2):

The program will do this `letters * 100 / words` before it does this `float L`. Since all the operands are integers, the result will be an (rounded!) integer before it is stored as a float. (Ditto `float S`). It is that "early rounding" that is making the L and S values too high. An easy solution is make one of the operands a float. (There's an easy and obvious choice)